# RESTful API Testbed with Swagger

Tags: api, rest, testing, automated-tests, swagger

I'm trying to develop an automated testing suite for a REST API. I've been told that Swagger would be the right tool to use to do this.
The API is being developed using the Spring Framework.

I can't figure out how I would use Swagger to do this.
From my understanding Swagger is used to create nice API documentation.
I've looked at [this Dreamfactory blog post](http://blog.dreamfactory.com/blog/bid/294825/Why-We-Like-Swagger-for-API-Docs) and it looks like they've got some kind of in browser testing functionality, but I don't think its really a test suite.

I've also taken a look at ServiceStack( and cucumber) but since its another framework I don't think it would work.

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/9AQ2k9OtHWM) google group discussion didn't see to point anywhere in particular either.

So, does anyone know how to develop a RESTful API testbed using Swagger?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Swagger will let you nicely document your API, and will help you do manual, live tests with swagger-ui in that you can easily fill in arguments and see the responses through a web ui. Try the Swagger demo as an example of what I am referring to. http://petstore.swagger.io/

I have not tried this, but this might be of interest for more automated testing against Swagger definitions.
https://github.com/Maks3w/SwaggerAssertions

Comment: I suggest you take a look at https://github.com/byjg/php-swagger-test also.

Answer (score 25):

As the other answers have mentioned, [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) provides a way to define and document your API endpoints, methods, responses, errors, and more. It does *not* do any sort of automated testing out of the box.

There are a few tools that can *read* a Swagger definition to created automated tests, though:

- [Assertible](https://assertible.com) is a tool where you can import your Swagger spec to automatically create tests and assertions for every endpoint and method. You can then set up monitoring, post deployment testing, and alerts. (Read the blog [Testing an API using Swagger](https://assertible.com/blog/testing-an-api-using-swagger)). It has a free plan with options to upgrade for more tests.
- [swagger-test](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-test) is an NPM package, if you're looking for something to integrate with your code. I haven't personally used it, but it does look active and useful.
- [Dredd](https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd) is another really cool open-source tool that will automate testing your Swagger spec against a live backend. This is also a CLI too, and it works with [API Blueprint in addition to Swagger](https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd#supported-api-description-formats).

There's others as well, because Swagger provides a good common language for API developers there's some great tools that are written on top of it.

Another answer mentioned to check out the [Commercial Tools](http://swagger.io/commercial-tools/) page on swagger.io, which has some more hosted services (free and paid).

*Full disclosure - I'm one of the co-founders of Assertible and would love to hear your feedback if you get a chance to use it.*

Comment: Useful, but very spammy.  Assertible is not a free tool given the constraints (only 15 free tests).

Comment: @Blaze - thanks, you're right that the phrasing was misleading. I updated the answer to reflect that more clearly :)

Answer (score 2):

You can find a lot of software using Swagger specification for (automated) testing of your REST API on http://swagger.io/commercial-tools/. But they are not free.

Answer (score 0):

Postman is great tool to test with Swagger apis. It can also store requests and responses. More details as follows
https://www.getpostman.com/docs/importing_swagger.

You might also want to look at the community tools according to languages at this page. http://swagger.io/open-source-integrations/

Answer (score 0):

I have written an [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/swagger-excel-sheets-wonderful-way-validating-rest-apis-aggarwal/) on how you can generate all the test logic by using the Swagger or OpenAPI specifications. And then feed test data through excel sheets. That way your test data and test logic remain separated and in future if your Swagger spec changes then you will be able to even quickly re-sync the test logic.