# How Web API could be automatically tested by using the power of Swagger?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I am working with ASP.NET Web API 2.0 we need to automate API testing using Swagger. How could I achieve that? Currently, we use Octopus for deployment of Projects to the server, is Swagger compatible with Octopus? So once our projects are deployed to the server using Octopus deployment, we would run automated testing.

Comment: [postman does this](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/03/07/writing-automated-tests-for-apis-using-postman/) or [swagger](https://assertible.com/blog/testing-an-api-using-swagger)

Comment: possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989965/restful-api-testbed-with-swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989965/restful-api-testbed-with-swagger)