# Get curl for all the API's present in the swagger UI

Tags: json, curl, swagger, swagger-ui

I am looking for a swagger API that could potentially generate curl requests for all the APIs present on the swagger UI.

Yes, there is a swagger API already available to get the API details in JSON format. Is there any way I can also get the curl requests for those APIs?

For example:

[Here](https://petstore.swagger.io) is the swagger UI for petstore

[Here](https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json) is the swagger API to get the data in JSON:

But on the swagger UI when we execute any API, it generates the curl request as well. **(Look at the very last of the image)**

[image]

The goal is to fire all the API's present on the Swagger UI but **not manually**. I need to automate this flow using curl requests. If anyhow, I can generate curls for all the APIs, then I can easily fire them and automate the process.

**I am open to any other solution as well.**

Comment: Use an [API testing tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43746716/113116) that can create tests from OpenAPI files.

Comment: Postman is a tool which is able to import swagger or OpenAPI document. Postman allows you to run a sequence of calls configured by you and to use data from responses to next calls. If you manage to do that, you will be able to schedule the tests automatically with Newman (the CLI brother of Postman)