# Automate Swagger to get list of API's and there details using python code

Tags: python, swagger

I have a requirement to automate all the API's in the project , so thought I can hit the swagger API and get list of API's it has with detail's like method json body and header.

If there is any other way to get those API's list at one shot is also helpfull.

Looking for a python code example.

Thanks in advance.

Note : If there is any doubt in question please do post than marking it invalid

Comment: Are you looking for an OpenAPI parser (to read the OpenAPI definition manually and extract the needed info)? If so, check out [openapi-parser](https://pypi.org/project/openapi-parser/) and [openapi3](https://github.com/Dorthu/openapi3). There're also [API testing tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989965/restful-api-testbed-with-swagger) that can generate tests from OpenAPI definitions and/or validate API responses against the OpenAPI definition.

Comment: Thanks for the response I think this is the one