# How to build JSON from remote Swagger documentation (websocket based API)

Tags: python-3.x, linux, swagger

I am currently grabbing the entire swagger.json contents:

```
swagger_link = "https://<SWAGGER_URL>/swagger/v1/swagger.json"
swagger_link_contents = requests.get(swagger_link)

#write the returned swagger to a file
swagger_return = swagger_link_contents.json()
with open ("swagger_raw.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(swagger_return, indent=4))
```

The file is filled with beautiful JSON now.  But there are a ton of objects in there, quite a few I don't need.  Say I wanted to grab the command "UpdateCookieCommand" from my document:

```
"parameters": [
{
"name": "command",
"in": "body",
"required": true,
"schema": {
"$ref": "#/definitions/UpdateCookieCommand"
},
"x-nullable": false
}
],
```

but it also has additional mentions later in the document...

```
UpdateCookieCommand": {
"allOf": [
{
"$ref": "#/definitions/BaseCommand"
},
{
"type": "object",
"required": [
"command",
"id"
],
```

The latter object is really what I want to take from the document.  It tells me what's required for a nominal API command to Update a Cookie. The hope is I could have a script that will look at every release and be able to absorb changes of the swagger and build new commands.

What methodology would you all recommend to accomplish this?  I considered making subprocess Linux commands to just awk, sed, grep it to what I want but maybe there's a more elegant way?  Also I won't know the amount of lines or location of anything as a new Swagger will be produced each release and my script will need to automatically run with a CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Create a Python client for an API based on its OpenAPI definition? Filter out unneeded (e.g. internal) endpoints/schemas from an OpenAPI document? Generate sample JSON based on a schema (e.g. for automated testing)? Something else?

Comment: I am hoping to implement automated API testing on our websocket based microservices.  I want this to be extensible and be able to handle changes in the swagger and build the new commands.  Since posting this question I do see there are some packages that can take swagger/OpenAPI documentation and convert them into a test suite but I haven't had success yet

Comment: There are many API testing tools that can generate tests from an OpenAPI document. See https://openapi.tools/#testing and [RESTful API Testbed with Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30989965/113116).

Comment: Thank you kindly.  I'll try and pursue some of those!